# Twitter Bootstrap Navigation White Space on Mobile

Tags: css, header, twitter-bootstrap

I am a little confused with the behaviour of my Twitter Bootstrap based navigation header. In Desktop based versions everything seems to be just fine, however when browsing from the iPhone/iPad I get a weird white spot on the right (which also seems to define the positioning of the Tumblr controls.

How do I go about debugging this? Anyone have any pointers? Thank you so much.

[image: top right white spot]

The actual code lives here http://thegodfounder.com/

**Edit 1:**

Changing the viewport to "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" as suggested by @baptme actually scales the viewport to where the black ends and hides everything on the right. What am I not seeing?

[image: changed viewport]

**Edit 2:**

1) Adding the suggestions of float:left & min-width:100% to body results in actually filling the white space, but there still seems to be something fishy: The Tumblr controls are still there in the middle of the page, and on pageload it loads right to the right of the Tumblr controls, as if there was some break point or so, but I am not aware of any? 
2) And am I not getting the concept in using the Bootstrap navbar right, when it's not supposed to be fixed to the top?

[image: loads weirdly]

Comment: you can try exporting the navbar code to something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with its upper tree and maybe some of the content. If the bug is there too it will be easier to debug. If not you should remove things from your page until the bug is no more, to find what's causing it.

Comment: The problem can be reproduced in a browser when the screen is smaller than the width set on `.container`, but to see the white space you have to scroll right. One way to fix it is to add `float: left` and `min-width: 100%` to `body`.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts you should post as an answer, your answer deserve more than a +1 on a comment.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts thanks, it does actually solve the white space thing, but not the weird viewport behaviour. I am probably not getting something, but I am not aware of any break-points in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

---

**EDIT:**

I remove the responsive behaviour and the `position:fixed` from the twitter bootstrap `.navbar` I end up with the same problem

[image: no responsive and no position fixed]

If you don't want the `.navbar` to have a `position:fixed` you can use media queries to avoid the `.navbav` width to be wider than the viewport.

---

**EDIT 2:**

The `float: left` and `min-width: 100%` to `body` from @MyHeadHurts comment is definitely the best way to fix it. Even if I wouldn't expect those 2 properties together to do that, it works.

---

**EDIT 3:**

Remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` if you want your page to scale according to the viewport.

Comment: Thanks @baptme! I have changed the viewport to your suggestion, check my edits in the question. Do you see what's happening?

Comment: So what is the right way to use the navbar without position fixed @baptme? Is it really that? Looks like a hacky way to achieve that behaviour to me? Thanks, appreciate the insights!

Comment: @Simon have you considered media queries like used in bootstrap-responsive.css? It's a good solution for small size devices.

Comment: well yes @baptme, but I wanted to keep it very simple and maintainable and build it fast. I haven't dealt with media queries enough yet (and I wanted to build one just for phones later, not iPad size). Isn't it true that if I made it right, then it should just show the whole page on the iPad and noz zoom in to left and cut almost half of the layout?

Comment: Any ideas for the viewport problem (@baptme, @MyHeadHurts)?

Comment: @simon i will have a look today, if you still have no correct answer the 27th contact me via comment and I will place a bounty on your question.

Comment: hm ok that was quite easy @baptme, I don't think I have entirely understood that viewport thing yet. So what's the point really? Thank you, I think I'll leave it like that for now. Although the iPhone version is a bit of a not legible joke.

Comment: @simon, the viewport is explained here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html, I hope it will makes thing clear as it is for me now.